# Javascript: Uncaught type error: cannot read property innerHTML of undefined

Tags: javascript

I cannot solve this error , it tells me that my buttons are undefined and cannot read their innerHtml attribute, the convert method is defined in the original code file and i have no problem with it,can you help me , the error comes from the code section below:

````
var btnsArr = document.getElementsByClassName("btn")

for (var i = 0; i < btnsArr.length; i++) {
    btnsArr[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
        Convert(btnsArr[i].innerHTML);
        return false;
    })
} ```
````

Comment: Use [event delegation](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) instead of assigning multiple event listeners — it’s more maintainable, and applies to dynamically added elements. E.g., use an [event argument](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#The_event_listener_callback)’s [`target`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Event/target). See [the tag info](/tags/event-delegation/info) and [What is DOM Event delegation?](/q/1687296/4642212).

Comment: _“it tells me that my buttons are undefined and cannot read their [`innerHTML` property]”_ — No; all it tells you is that `btnsArr[i]` is `undefined`. How are you concluding that `btnsArr[i]` is one of your buttons? Have you checked what `i` is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of scoping in javascript aka closure inside loop problem. When getting to the function execution at runtime, i has completed its loop and is out of bound for the array.

You need to bound the variable:

```
for (var i = 0; i < btnsArr.length; i++) {
    (function(x) {
        btnsArr[x].addEventListener("click", function () {
            Convert(btnsArr[x].innerHTML);
            return false;
        });
    })(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a very common issue in the code, is that your array of elements (`btnsArr`) is used to define the maximum index for your `for`. The issue here is that `btnsArr.length` must be `btnsArr.length - 1` instead.

why?
if `btnsArr` has 3 elements it's range will be from 0 to 2, but your `for` is expecting from 0 to 3 (because `btnsArr.length` is 3). Then, probably it is failing in the last array element `btnsArr[3]` that does not exist.

I hope that it helps at least to cover some exception.